# What is the default value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Tags: header, cors, default-value, same-origin-policy

Is "*" or the server's URI the default value for Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?
If the header is not set, does it mean that every origin has access to the resource?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no default value.

If it isn't set, then it isn't set. If it is set, then it must have an explicit value.

> If the header is not set, does it mean that every origin has access to the resource?

No. It means that the Same Origin Policy is enforced as normal. No origins are granted permission.

> the server's URI

There is no reason to ever set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to be the server's own URL. Same Origin requests don't need permission from CORS.

Comment: I removed the  Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from the backend in question on the server side and yet when I request a resource from that backend, with a header "Origin : http://test.test" (with postman), I get a 200 response and the resource. Cross-origin should be forbidden in this case. Is that correct?

Comment: Is this the reason applications/ websites hosted on Netlify/ Heroku/ Github Pages are not visible when accessing it from non configured host, for example, when I CNAME my own domain to the netlify application? (You get a generic: "Application not found" type message)

Comment: @ButterHub — No.

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue — This answer explains the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

As the name `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` itself suggests, the `Allow-Origin` part of the name asks us the tell the origin names which are allowed to request resources. That clearly means the logical virtual-ish (which actually does not exist and illogical to set) default value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is the origin itself on which the resource is hosted.

> Is "*" or the server's URI the default value for
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

If that was the case, then every organization's server who do not set the header are at a great threat !!

Answer (score -1):

Came across this looking for the headers that work without CORS and found this nice safe list from Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_request_header

```
A CORS-safelisted request header is one of the following HTTP headers:

Accept,
Accept-Language,
Content-Language,
Content-Type.
```